# Random number generator two digit

Tags: java

```
package com.nusecond.Code;
import java.util.*;

public class Code {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Random random=new Random();
        for(int j=10;j<=99;j++){        
           int num=random.nextInt(100) ;
           //ssLong i=System.currentTimeMillis();
           //String result = String.format("%04d", i % 10000);
           System.out.println("Code generated:"  +num);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to print two digit random numbers between 10 and 99.

Note : I want only one number every time I run the program.

Comment: One number when run the program means?

Comment: "I want only one number" Why do you have a loop that runs from 10 to 99? That will give you 89 numbers between 0 and 99.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random integers in a range with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java)

Comment: Simple. `random.nextInt(90) + 10 ;` will always give you a number between 10 and 99.

Answer (score 4):

With random numbers, if you need to start at a certain number, just add the random number to that lower limit. The upper limit passed to the random number will be the upper bounds minus the lower limit.

```
int num = random.nextInt(90) + 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```
private static int showRandomInteger(int aStart, int aEnd, Random aRandom){
    if (aStart > aEnd) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Start cannot exceed End.");
    }
    //get the range, casting to long to avoid overflow problems
    long range = (long)aEnd - (long)aStart + 1;
    // compute a fraction of the range, 0 <= frac < range
    long fraction = (long)(range * aRandom.nextDouble());
    int randomNumber =  (int)(fraction + aStart);    
    return randomNumber;
}
```

The parameters you have to pass to this method are:

- `aStart` : your starting value(i.e. 10 in you case)
- `aEnd` : your ending value(i.e 99 in your case)
- `aRandom` : this would be an object of the `Random` class.(`Random random=new Random();`)

Answer (score 0):

Random random = new Random();

// generate a random integer from 10 to 90 i.e 2 digit random no.

```
int abc =  10+random.nextInt(90);
```

Answer (score 0):

java code to generate random two digit number.

```
    import java.util.*;

public class RandomNumbers{
        public static void main(String[] args){
                Random rand = new Random();
                int random=rand.nextInt(90)+10; //generates random no. between 10 and 100
                System.out.println(random);
        }
}
```